# Calculate double integral $\iint_A \sin (x+y) dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, area

Calculate double integral $$\iint_A \sin (x+y) dxdy$$
where:
$$A=\{ \left(x,y \right)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \le x \le \pi, 0 \le y \le \pi\}$$
How to calculate that? $x+y$ in sin is confusing as i do not know how to change it to iterated integral or maybe is there a different method to calculate that?

Comment: Use the equivalence: $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$ and then integrate twice.

Comment: For a constant $y$, the function $f(x)  = \sin(x+y)$ has an antiderivative, namely $F(x) = -\cos(x + y)$. You can just do iterated integration using this fact.

Comment: could you please show how to deal with this in more details? As still i have problems with that

Comment: When integrating with respect to x you hold y constant. So you can use integration by substitution for the first integral. Once the integral is set up i.e. you've found the limits etc. Multiple integrals are just the same as "normal" (single variable) integrals. Just do them one at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to follow the path outlined by John Hughes' comment, but even quicker to see that the integral must be $0$ due to symmetry.

Along the diagonal $x+y=\pi$, we have $\sin(x+y)=0$. A point above the diagonal has a negative value that corresponds exactly to the positive value at the point you get by reflecting across the diagonal. (And the domain of integration $A$ is invariant under this reflection).

Comment: Why is the domain invariant under reflection?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Because a square is symmetric under reflection in its diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

Using John Hughes' comment, you get

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x+y)dydx=\int_0^{\pi}\bigg[-\cos(x+y)\bigg]_{y=0}^{y=\pi}\;dx=\int_0^{\pi}\big(-\cos(x+\pi)-(-\cos x)\big)dx$

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle=\int_0^{\pi}2\cos x \;dx=2\big[\sin x\big]_0^{\pi}=0$  $\;\;\;$(using that $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos x$)